# python: I want to find the first record in google place result but getting first character

Tags: python, google-maps

I'm using google place API to return a list of locations. I would like to find the first name from the result set. I'm getting a list of values, but when I try to get just the first name, it gives me the first character instead.

```
name2 = simplejson.dumps([s['name'] for s in result['results']], indent=0)[0]
```

Obviously, there has to be a better way to get what I want, but I haven't found it. Seems like I'm missing something pretty basic. Following is the whole function:

```
import simplejson, urllib


PLACE_SEARCH = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json'

def placelatlng(name,city, state,  sensor,**geo_args):
    geo_args.update({
        'name': name,
        'city': city,
        'state': state,       
        'sensor': sensor  
    })  
    concat=name+'+'+city+'+'+state 
    query =  {"query": concat }

    key="MyKey"
    url = PLACE_SEARCH + '?' + urllib.unquote(urllib.urlencode(query))+ '&'  + "sensor="+sensor +'&' + "key="+key
    result = simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
    name2 = simplejson.dumps([s['name'] for s in result['results']], indent=0)
```

Thanks.

Comment: remove unquote(), pass dictionary with query parameters (including sensor, key to urlencode().

Comment: Provide a working key to get help faster, @jabs

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - I'll try that as well. Your solution below worked, but trying other approaches is good too. Thanks.

Comment: @hd1 - I'd rather not add the key, since searches are limited. Maybe I'm overly cautious, but keys aren't that hard to get. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dumps() returns a string. `[0]` gets the first character in it.

To get the first result's name:

```
print result['results'][0]['name']
```